# diffrence between isSuccess and onSuccess in react-query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I want to do some logic when useMutaion is success, and I don't know what and when should I use, 'isSuccess' the boolean or 'onSuccess' the callback function?

```js
 const {
    mutate: createRoom,
    isLoading,
    isError,
    isSuccess,
  } = useCreateRooom();
```

Answer (score 1):

> diffrence between isSuccess and onSuccess

Depends what exactly you want to do when the request has succeeded. If you want display some JSX permanently (until *the flag* changes), `isSuccess` flag may be useful.

```
{isSuccess && <div>Request success</div>}
```

However if you want to do something once when succeeded, e.g. show a tooltip or call some cleanup function - `onSuccess` may be better option.

```
onSuccess(() => {
   showTooltip('Success!', 5000);
   clearState();
});
```